# Blank HTML5 Banners after loading

Tags: html, banner, banner-ads

We have this website arabic.sport360.com

Since we started using HTML5 banners, we face most of the time blank banners!

It shows the banner for a milliseconds, then it become white.

Any body can help me with this?

Comment: You should at least make an effort to provide some codes

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a spritesheet? I've experienced something like this, and it resolved when I loaded graphics individually rather than using a spritesheet.